# Zend framework ajax request without layout

Tags: php, zend-framework

AM new to zend framework and previously used laravel and yii2 and would simply like to return a json array without using the phtml layout.

In my controller action i have

```
class Lms_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

      public function saveTestAction(){
        return ["json"=>1]
       }
 }
```

In my javascript code i have

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $sBaseUrl; ?>/lms/index/save-test/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            item:'test'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log("response is ", response);

        },
        error: function(e){
          
           console.log("error is ", e);
        }
    });
```

But the above returns an error of

```
script 'index/save-meeting.phtml' not found
```

Is there a way in zend to simply perform an ajax request and return response just like in other frameworks in php like yii2 or laravel. I expected to receive a json array as response with

```
{json:1}
```

as the output on the console.log

What am i missing out.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller override init method

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
    $this->_helper->json->suppressExit = true;
}
```

In your action

```
public function whateverAction()
{
    // your code

   $this->_helper->json($yourData); 
   // No "return" is required
}
```

In the init method:

Call to "disableLayout" make your controller not to look for a template

Call to "setNoRender" make you action not to look for a view script

Call to "setHeader" will set the content type for json

Set suppressExit to true make calls to "_helper->json" not to exit ZF1 dispatch loop, otherwise "postDispatch" will not be called.